# Is there a way to measure the time it takes to switch from one webpage to another in selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a webpage full of questions, when they are answered the user clicks a 'submit' button to proceed to the next page. Is there a way to measure the time it takes to load the next page in selenium webdriver? Programming language is c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StopWatch` to measure the time spent between the click and an element is visible on the new page.

```
var Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

//first page - click
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("submit-button")).Click();
Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

//set waiting period
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

//second page - wait for element to be available.
var element = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("id-on-second-page"));

//stop timer
s.Stop();

//reset waiting period
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: ImplicitlyWait() shouldn't be used like that. If you want to wait for an element to appear, use WebDriverWait. You should read more [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ITimeouts_ImplicitlyWait.htm), [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits), and [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `StopWatch`,  a good fit here

> to measure the time it takes to load the next page in selenium webdriver

will be the [LoadableComponent](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/LoadableComponent.html), since it'll [provide you](https://gist.github.com/ksummerlin/2591617) with the page's load state once it's ready via

```
protected override bool EvaluateLoadedStatus(){}
```

Which is pretty much the same as [JAVA](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent)'s

```
@Override  
protected void isLoaded() throws Error {}
```

Another option to consider is the `IJavaScriptExecutor` capability to the read the document state. Simple code:

```
public Boolean isPageLoaded(WebDriver driver)
        {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
```